# convex function related

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb R^n\to [0,\infty)$ be $C^1$ convex function such that $F(\alpha x)=\alpha^2F(x)$ for $\alpha>0$ and for $u,v$ are two positive differential functions with $u>0$. Then prove that $$F(\nabla v)\geq\frac{v^2}{u^2} F(\nabla u)+\langle\nabla F(\nabla u),\nabla v\rangle\frac vu-\langle\nabla F(\nabla u),\nabla u\rangle \frac{v^2}{u^2}$$
where $\langle,\rangle$ denotes the inner product.

I am trying to prove this one by using convexity but I can't get it.

Comment: Hint: Since you assume $u,v$ are positive, you want to show
$$
F(\nabla v)\geq F\left(\frac vu\nabla u\right)+\left\langle\frac vu\nabla F(\nabla u),\nabla v-\frac vu\nabla u\right\rangle.
$$

Comment: yes but how to do that?

Comment: Use $F(\alpha x)=\alpha^2 F(x)$ to show $\langle\nabla F(\alpha x),h\rangle=\langle\alpha\nabla F(x),h\rangle$.  Now put $x=\nabla u$, $\alpha=\frac vu$ and a suitable $h$.  Finally, use convexity.

Comment: Thanks @user10354138